# SVN Multiple Commands single revision

Tags: linux, unix, svn, version-control, google-code

I want to do something like
`svn add dir1 dir2; svn ci dir1 dir2` but have it be only 1 revision. Is there a way to do this?

P.S. Is this the correct way to add new folders (with contents) to the repository? We are restructuring the trunk, so I cleared it out and plan on putting these directories with their contents in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add, delete, edit as many files as you want in a single revision.  When you commit the changes a revision is made, not when you do a single action such as add or remove a folder.

Just do everything you want to do THEN commit to the SVN.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. Like if I want to import this directory and that directory. Each one causes a revision.

Comment: @person - no it doesn't. Only a `svn ci` causes a new revision.

Comment: I agree with rq. The `svn add` doesn't do an implicit commit. If you do `add` without `ci` (aka `commit`), your directories are not added to the subversion repository.